Is the following proof that the sequence converges towards 0 correct?
I am unsure if my thought process is correct and would really appreciate it if somebody went over it. I have to show that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1} {(n+n)^3} $ = 0, so here is my proof. We need a N so that n> N : $ |\frac {1} {(n+n)^3}| < \epsilon $, we know that n > 0, it follows that $ \frac {1} {(n+n)^3} < \epsilon \iff (n+n)^3 > \frac {1} {\epsilon} $ , if we chose $ N = \frac {1} {\epsilon} $ then $ |\frac {1} {(n+n)^3} -0| = \frac {1} {(n+n)^3} < \epsilon$ and thus the limit as n goes towards infinity equals 0? Would that be correct?

of course it should be $ | \frac {1} {(n+n)^3} -0|   < \epsilon $ at the beginning of the third line.

Why is it $\frac{1}{(n+n)^3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{(2n)^3}$?

Why not write $n+n$ as $2n$ then simplify to $\frac{1}{8n^3}$?  EDIT: Mike sent that 5 seconds before mine :|

Kindof, the definition is

For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for any $n>N$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

In your case, if you choose $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, then $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ implies, $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ implies $\frac{1}{8n^3}<\frac{1}{8}\epsilon^3\neq \epsilon$.
Technically this works for $\epsilon\leq2\sqrt{2}$, but it's cleaner to use $N=(\frac{\epsilon}{8})^{1/3}$.

Wow thanks a lot Sir, never thought that I would get a nice answer to my questions it's always some salty comments which make it really hard for beginners to get out of their comfort zone and ask the more knowledgable persons.

No problem, this site is filled with lots of nice people who have also helped me out when I needed it. There are also those who like to follow strict guidelines (see Mike above) when they could simply answer the question or ignore it. That's not to say rules (and their enforcers) aren't needed, otherwise the site would be filled with a spam of homework problems. My best advice is to learn the site guidelines, follow them as best as possible, and ignore salty comments.

What is $f(x) $ in the third line of the answer ?
